# Stop AutoKey script if Window is not match and print the ShortCut literal

Tags: autokey

i use a AutoKey (autokey-gtk 0.95.10) script with the shortcut **ü**

it get errors with:

```
winTitle = window.get_active_title()
winClass = window.get_active_class()
if winTitle != "0 A.D." or winClass != 'pyrogenesis.pyrogenesis':   
    keyboard.send_keys("ü")
```

but **not** with shorter Version:

```
winTitle = window.get_active_title()
if winTitle != "0 A.D.":   
    keyboard.send_keys("ü")
```

got Errors and the CPU is really high at 7%:

[image]

If i run this AutoKey (autokey-gtk 0.95.10) script again it show no errors but does nothing.
CPU still high and i need to shutdown it (no normal exit).

i don't understand why this happens. BTW as workaround its good enough for me to check only the window name. The better solution should check for class and window name.

[image]

Comment: If you are interested in my intermediate result: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/84c79a7093f20fbe77b7ba08271c74e9

Comment: i restarted the computer and the error never came back. should I delete the question?